# How to implement Quick Buy Functionality In BigCommerce Store?

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

We want to achieve Quick Buy Functionality in Big-commerce Store.  This functionality, we want to achieve on the results of quick search.

Please find attached screenshot for the reference. Customer can quickly add to cart the products with quantity while quick search and finally can checkout from the quick search window itself.

Please refer attached screenshot.

Can anyone help, what changes need to be done in template files to achieve this functionality?

[Quick Buy Functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTjN4.png)

Comment: do you expect a complete implementation of your requirement? Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ulrich Thank you Ulrich. I have edited my question-details.

Answer (score 1):

**BigCommerce Stencil**

You can add items to the cart from any page in your store via the AJAX API  seen [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/remote-api-example).

```
// add item to cart
utils.api.cart.itemAdd(productId, quantity, options, (err, response) => {
  let options = {
            template: 'cart/preview',
            params: {
                suggest: response.data.cart_item.id
            },
            config: {
                cart: {
                    suggestions: {
                        limit: 4
                    }
                }
            }
        };
}
```

**BigCommerce Blueprint**

In blueprint, it's even easier. Just hit this URL with the products ID.

```
http://www.STOREURL.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id=PRODUCTID
```

Or for products with variations.

```
http://www.STOREURL.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id=PRODUCTID&variation_id=VARIATIONID
```

Not sure how you'd get the variation IDs in the quicksearch tab, but this is a good start. Also, checkout the **quicksearch.js** file in the js directory.

Comment: The screenshot provided shows a Blueprint theme I believe and this resolution is specific to Stencil. Definitely a great answer, just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Whoops. Long week.

Comment: @tim-diztinct . Thank you tim-diztinct, How we can get Product Id in any template file in BigCommerce ? I have used global variable "%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%". But not able to get Product Id in template file.

Comment: For your case, you'd need to reference the %%GLOBAL_ProductId%% inside a product snippet loop. For example - The HomeFeaturedProducts.html Panel, calls the HomeFeaturedProductsItem.html snippet which is a loop of each product <li>. Add your "Quick Buy" button in a product snippet, creating your URL with the ProductID, and you will have dynamic add to cart buttons in each list item.

Comment: @tim-diztinct . Thank you .Current Structure of Quick Search template file(Snippets/SearchResultAJAXProduct.html) is like following. Can you please guide, how can i get Product Id using product snippet?

Comment: <tr class="QuickSearchResult">
 <td class="QuickSearchResultImage %%GLOBAL_ProductNoImageClassName%%">
  %%GLOBAL_ProductImage%%
 </td>

 <td class="QuickSearchResultMeta">
  <div class="QuickSearchResultName"><a href="%%GLOBAL_ProductURL%%" title="%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%">%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%</a></div>
  <span class="Price">%%GLOBAL_ProductPrice%%</span>
  %%GLOBAL_ProductRatingImage%%
 </td>
</tr>